# Increasing/decreasing space between stars in Android default RatingBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to add space between the stars in Android default RatingBar. But unfortunately haven't got any documentation regarding this. Is there any way we can increase/decrease space between the stars in Android default RatingBar.

```
    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1"
    />
```

p.s. I don't want to create a png and then do it. Would be helpful if it can be done in the default RatingBar.

Comment: I have added a feature request, please vote for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230511